# Json is not properly binded as c# object

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

My app is made in `ASP.NET MVC 5`. User can use search form which is displaying filtered data. Now I want to add button which will export displayed data.

To do this I am sending `Search` object to view and save it in html. Now When clicking export button I want to pass this object to controller, get data from database using this `Search` object and save results as `text`.

The thing is I cant bind json to `c#` object. Thats my `view`:

```
<div id="originalForm" style="visibility:hidden">
    @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))
</div>
```

This is my `ajax` code:

```
function exportRaportToCsv() {
    var $formData = $('#originalForm').text();
    var allIds = getCheckedIds();

    var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({
        ids: allIds,
        search: $formData
    });


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("ExportToCsv", "BankCosts")',
        data: dataToSend,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (datar) {
            window.location = '/BankCosts/Download?fileGuid=' + response.FileGuid
                + '&filename=' + response.FileName;
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
        },
    });
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportToCsv(string[] ids, Search search)
{
    // search is null here
}
```

When I spy sending data with `Fiddler` I can see, that I am passing this:

```
{"ids":[],"search":"\n    {\"ID\":0,\"DateFrom\":\"2018-06-23T00:00:00\",\"DateTo\":\"2018-06-25T00:00:00\",\"hasUnrecognizedStatus\":false,\"skippedSearchResults\":0,\"paginationLimit\":100}\n"}
```

I think it is worth to mention, that `ids` is properly passed. If it contains data, that data is passed. I think the problem is that I have `\` in my `json`. How can I remove this? Is there something wrong with my `ajax`?

When I use `console.log` to print `$formData` I can see that `\` characters are gone and it looks better:

```
{"ID":0,"DateFrom":"2018-06-23T00:00:00","DateTo":"2018-06-25T00:00:00","hasUnrecognizedStatus":false,"skippedSearchResults":0,"paginationLimit":100}
```

Comment: When you fetch the contents of `#originalForm` you should deserialize it before assigning it to `dataToSend.search`.

Comment: Your JSON is fine. Fiddler shows it in different way to you. Whats the Issue you are getting?

Comment: why dont you pass it as string. then convert it to object in the server side, you can also create custom binding

Comment: @SangramNandkhile as I wrote search is null when passed to controller

Comment: @fredrik thanks! That did the work!

Comment: @AKhudairy well, if MVC can do something for me, I want to use it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you are using

> JSON.stringify

the search value posted in string format not object

> Search

so

Try replace your controller with this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportToCsv(string[] ids, string search)
{
  //then deserialize search json like
  Search objSearch = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Search>(search);
}
```

or

```
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult ExportToCsv(string[] ids, JObject search)
    {
  //then deserialize search json like
     Search objSearch = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Search > 
    (dataModel["search"].ToString());

}
```

**View**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("ExportToCsv", "BankCosts")',
    data:{ids= allIds.toString(),search:JSON.stringify($formData)}
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (datar) {
        window.location = '/BankCosts/Download?fileGuid=' + response.FileGuid
            + '&filename=' + response.FileName;
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
    },
});
```

Comment: Thats working too! I already found another solution. I changed my code to: `search: $.parseJSON($formData)` and now this is working!

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportToCsv(string[] ids,[FromBody]Search search)
{
}
```

Try adding FromBody if your Search model is ok it should work.

Answer (score 0):

based on your comments, I think that search object already stringified, so you don't need to stringify it.

just make your json like this

```
var dataToSend = {
    "ids": allIds,
    "search": $formData
};
```

Comment: Thats not working. Without `stringify` the passed data is not json, but string. What did the trick was deserializing `formData` by `search: $.parseJSON($formData)`

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse() to transforms JSON string to a JavaScript object. Your $('#originalForm').text() is a JSON string actually.

```
        var $formData = JSON.parse($('#originalForm').text());
        var allIds = getCheckedIds();

       var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({
            ids: allIds,
            search: $formData
            });
```

In your case, $formData is a string (JSON string actually). So JSON.stringify() again trying to convert to JSON string which is already a JSON string that's causing unnecessary '/' character in form data that you are posting.

Make sure to set the content type to 'application/json' in ajax call properties Otherwise MVC model binder will not be able to map and fill .NET model from JSON posted data. 
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",